# Scene2dUI in Libgdx and html5

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx, scene2d

I can't normally launch html5 the version of application in which there are scene2d ui elements. After transition to the Screen with Scene2dUI it turns out here[image: transition to the Screen with Scene2dUI]

To look as application "works" it is possible.

The last version of a plug-in of gwt for Eclipse is set.

Why so occurs? The android and a desktop of the version work  good.

In archive a test project. The source code from this [example](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java)
The project was developed in Intellij Idea, html5 the version was compiled in Eclipse. `Version Libgdx libgdx-nightly-20121213.zip`. In http:// of compiled html5 isn't present.

In game where there are screens from use of Scene2d and screens with Scene2dUI screens without Scene2dUI work very well. If I switch to the screen from Scene2dUI there is an error as now on http://

Edit: 
[Issue 1169](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1169)

Comment: @X.Jacobs after your editing links to source codes of an example were gone. Why you made it?

Comment: they are still there, click on blue underlined words :) edit: you're right! fixed

Comment: I found them) they appeared) Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, I have the same problem. could you please write your efforts to solve?

Comment: I debugged my codes and find out that the problem is in "new Stage()".
I posted an issue in libgdx issues:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1166&sort=-id

Comment: @Aliaaa It not the decision, but only a roundabout way what to launch the above-stated example. 
Now I will be engaged in writing of the report on an error.
So.  In the above-stated example the error arises because of use of the classes "window" and "dialog". 
If to change "window" for "desktop", it will turn out: [link](http://spravka.idua.org/123/).
Everything works, but the left upper button which causes a dialog still causes the application to generate an error. /Offtop. on this site there are personal messages?/

Comment: hey it now works! it seems that there was a bug and now I can run it.
just pull the codes from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed. just get a pull the sources from github to update.
related post: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2704

Comment: classes Dialog and Window still don't work in the web version.

Comment: yes unfortunately it still has problems with Dialog and Window :(